# Cargar datos en columnas especificas

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel, eloquent

Tengo una collection que me trae datos de la tabla Estacion, tabla Equipo relacionado a esa estacion y los parametros que cada Equipo puede medir.Esto lo obtengo a traves de las relaciones en los modelos.

```
 Estacion
 Equipo 
 Equipo_estacion
 Parametro
 Equipo_Parametro
```

Obtengo una collection Con los datos Estacion>Equipo>parametro

en el controller paso un arreglo ordenado con la posicion y nombre de los parametros, este lo comparo con los obtenido de la base

```
$param_header = array('MP10','MP25','SO2','NO2','CO','O3','BC');
```

y quiero cargar en la tabla cada campo donde una estacion tiene un equipo que mide ese parametro

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el primer dato de la fila lo carga en la posicion correcta, es decir en la estacion Bodega1 , existe un equipo que mide el parametro SO2 y otro que mide NO2, en la imagen NO2 no corresponde con su columna correspondiente y lo mismo sucede en algunas de las siguientes filas.

```
  @foreach($est_equi as $item1)
           @foreach($item1->equipos as $equipo)

          <tr> 

            <td>{{ $item1->region_id }} </td>
            <td>{{ $item1->nombre .'-' . $item1->id   }} </td>

            @foreach($equipo->parametros as $key=>$param)
               @php ($i = 0) 

               //Aca comprueba en que posicion dentro del arreglo esta el parametro

              {!! $posicion = array_search($param->nombre, $param_header) !!}
                 {{ 'Las posicion es :' .$offset }}</br> 

                  @while ($i < 7)

                    @if($i == $posicion)
                        <td>{{ $param->nombre}} </td>
                        @break;
                    @else
                        <td> no </td>
                    @endif   
                  @php ( $i++ )     

                  @endwhile       
            @endforeach

          </tr>
```

Comment: Hola Rodrigo, puedes cambiar la foto por el codigo en formato texto? (la otra foto con la tabla, si es posible, tambien) Un saludo

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema aquí?

Comment: Al igual que en la pregunta anterior que hiciste, también falta información.

Comment: Hola, Si se fijan en la imagen , en la primera fila, el parametro SO2 esta bajo la columna SO2 ,pero el 2do parametro NO2 lo posiciona bajo otra columna ya que algo falla en el recorrido dentro del while cuando encuentro que la posicion del primer parametro es igual a la variable $i , deberia imprimir el parametro bajo su columna respectiva, en el primer recorrido lo hace bien, pero para el segundo parametro no

Comment: Sería interesante ver como obtienes los datos, asumo que tienes esa información en el controlador.

Comment: $est_equi = Estacion::with('equipos.parametros')->orderBy('region_id')->get(); esto crea una collection con todas las realciones

Comment: ¿de dónde sale `$offset`?

Comment: ¿todos los equipos tienen siete parámetros? No es clara tampoco esa parte. Debes tener en cuenta que nosotros no conocemos tu proyecto ni el contexto, por lo cual tus explicaciones deben ser más claras, con la mayor cantidad de código pertinente posible.

Comment: cambie el nombre de $offset a $posicion , la posicion dentro del arreglo al hacer la comparacion entre el dato obtenido de la base, y el arreglo que cree $param_header, con los datos ordenados segun posicion en la columna, asi si el array_search encuentra que $param->nombre tiene la posicion 1 , este al recorrerlo lo despliego en la posicion 1 bajo MP2.5 ya que el contador parte de 0, la posicion 0 seria la columna MP10.

Comment: La verdad es que todo esto lo puedes explicar más fácil si pones el código respectivo en la pregunta, tal vez así podamos entender mejor.

Comment: @RodrigoRose Por favor revisa este enlace: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Setea el parametro en la columna que corresponda algo como:

```
<tr> 
    @foreach($equipo->parametros as $key=>$param)
        // COLUMNA 1
        <td>{{ $param->parametro_1 }}</td>
        // COLUMNA 2
        <td>{{ $param->parametro_2 }}</td>
        // COLUMNA 3
        <td>{{ $param->parametro_3 }}</td>
        // COLUMNA 4
        <td>{{ $param->parametro_4 }}</td>
        // COLUMNA 5
        <td>{{ $param->parametro_5 }}</td>

        // COLUMNA N
        <td>{{ $param->parametro_N }}</td>
    @endforeach
</tr>
```

Comment: en el primer loop foreach $param-nombre es "SO2",este solo va a la columna 3, solo algunas columnas tienen parametros,  ahi la complejidad, para las que no llevan el parametro debo imprimir un td vacio

Comment: Solo muestra las estaciones con equipos que contienen parametros.